# Using calculateroute in HERE to retrieve road names and it stops providing after first waypoint

Tags: here-api

Problem:

*Road names are given from origin until the first waypoint. While it is expected that Road names are given from Origin to Destination.

Request parameters I am using:

```
routeRequestParams = {
    mode: 'fastest;truck',
    representation: 'display',
    routeattributes : 'waypoints,summary,shape,legs,summaryByCountry',
    maneuverattributes: 'direction,action,roadName,roadNumber',
    country:'USA',
    waypoint0: "47.60358,-122.32945",  //origin waypoint
    waypoint1: "42.4065,-113.3798",     //when a middle waypoint is added, road names are given till this waypoint and not the destination
    waypoint2: "42.2821,-83.74847",    //destination waypoint
};
```

Parameters can be found here:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/resource-calculate-route.html

Comment: Can you please trace the HTTPRest request and add this? It would be useful but of course remove you credentials ;-)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what is required in the httpREST trace and when I copy the response from maneuver object from which I am trying to retrieve roadnames
result.response.route[0].leg[0].maneuver:- it's too long to post

Comment: Just trace the HTTPRest request and provide it. Then we can analyze it and the response.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, how do you trace the HTTPRest request?

Answer (score 0):

Below request gives the maneuverattributes(roadname, roadnumber) from origin to destination.

```
https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id=xxxx&app_code=yyyy&waypoint0=47.60358,-122.32945&waypoint1=42.4065,-113.3798&waypoint2=42.2821,-83.74847&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled&representation=display&routeattributes=waypoints,summary,legs,summaryByCountry&maneuverattributes=direction,action,roadName,roadNumber
```

Could you please verify your request again and provide your output if you still don't find the roadnames?

Comment: The problem is not that I am not receiving roadnames or road numbers.

The problem is that I am receiving the road numbers for roads between Waypoint0 and Waypoint1 but it leaves out road numbers between Waypoint1 and Waypoint2,
 while I should be receiving all the road numbers  between Waypoint0 and Waypoint2.

Comment: Could you please share your curl or API call if possible

Comment: var testroadnumbers=[];
var testroadnames=[];
var testresult;
    function gettestroads(){
        var url="https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id="+APPLICATION_ID+"&app_code="+APPLICATION_CODE+"&waypoint0=47.60358,-122.32945&waypoint1=42.4065,-113.3798&waypoint2=42.2821,-83.74847&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled&representation=display&routeattributes=waypoints,summary,legs,summaryByCountry&maneuverattributes=direction,action,roadName,roadNumber";

Comment: testroadnames=[];
        testroadnumbers=[];
              $.get( url, function( result ) {
            testresult=result;
var previouspush="";
        var previouspush2="";
        var temproadarray=testresult.response.route[0].leg[0].maneuver;
for(a=0;a<temproadarray.length;a++) {
if(a==0){
if(temproadarray[a].roadName!=""){
testroadnames.push(temproadarray[a].roadName);
previouspush=temproadarray[a].roadName;
 }
 }

Comment: else{
if(previouspush==temproadarray[a].roadName){
  }
 else{
 if(temproadarray[a].roadName==""){
 }
else{
testroadnames.push(temproadarray[a].roadName);
previouspush=temproadarray[a].roadName;
}
}
}}

Comment: for(b=0;b<temproadarray.length;b++){
if(b==0){
if(temproadarray[b].roadNumber!=""){
testroadnumbers.push(temproadarray[b].roadNumber);
previouspush2=temproadarray[b].roadNumber;
}
}
else{
if(previouspush2==temproadarray[b].roadNumber){
}
else{
if(temproadarray[b].roadNumber==""){
}
else{
testroadnumbers.push(temproadarray[b].roadNumber);
previouspush2=temproadarray[b].roadNumber;
 }
 }
 }
 }
});

Comment: these road numbers are returned by the request they provided:-
["I-90", "I-82", "I-84", "ID-81"]

roadnames:-
["James St", "6th Ave", "Mountains To Sound Greenway", "Lacey V Murrow Brg", "Thomas S Tom Foley Memorial Hwy", "McNary Hwy", "Old Oregon Trail Hwy", "Yale Rd", "S Highway 81", "E 800 S", "S 2050 E"]

Comment: You can see the road numbers provided end halfway into the trip after waypoint 1.

Comment: Getting roadnames with below API call.. please try with this by replacing your app_id and app_code : 
https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id=xxxx&app_code=xxxx&waypoint0=47.60358,-122.32945&waypoint1=42.4065,-113.3798&waypoint2=42.2821,-83.74847&mode=fastest;truck